# Create chart using json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, angular-chart

I have below JSON data through which I am trying to create line chart using [AngularJS](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) . However using map function, I am able to get the `$scope.labels` but not able to form `$scope.series` and `$scope.data`.

Here is my JS code:

```
var source = [
  {"DE":2,"NP":20,"BD":28,"TW":1,
  "end_time":"2016-07-05T07:00:00+0000","date":"01-01-2011"},
  {"DE":5,"NP":11,"BD":22,"BE":2,"FJ":2,
  "end_time":"2016-07-06T07:00:00+0000","date":"01-09-2011"},
  {"DE":5,"NP":24,"BD":29,
  "end_time":"2016-07-07T07:00:00+0000","date":"01-11-2011"}
]
var $scope = {};
$scope.labels = [];
$scope.data = [];
$scope.series = [];


source.forEach(function(item){
  $scope.labels.push(item.end_time)
})
```

How to fetch data from JSON to form series like below and data.

```
$scope.series = ["DE","NP","BD","TW"]

$scope.data = [] ---> //Stuck here in forming data
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obcy91zs/1/)

Comment: You should only look up the documentation for angular. There is a module called $http, and there is plenty of examples how to do what you want.

Here is the url for $http doc
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

If you change the way you iterate over the data, this should become fairly trivial:

```
angular.forEach(source, function(item){
  $scope.labels.push(item.end_time);
  angular.forEach(item, function(val, key) {
    if(key === 'end_time') return;
    $scope.data.push(val);
    $scope.series.push(key);
  });
})
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/obcy91zs/2/)

Angular's [`forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) will help you to iterate over objects.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue. But I need $scope.series as 2D array to create chart . Example -$scope.data = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  ]; and $scope.data has duplicate values